# Measurement recognition using a golden sample approach

Tags: matlab, image-processing, feature-detection, measurement

I would like to find a way of calssification depending on the golden sample approach.

I have 2 measured objects (they are identical in everything except the quality if the object). The simple approach is to subtract the two measurement and to get the difference result.

My question now what is the most common apporach to classify the measurement whethere is good or bad?

should I measure the standard deviation of the defference measurement?

Or is there any other way totally different?

I would do that using MATLAB

Any suggestions, please?

Many thanks in advance for your support